# What does 外地人能干的，北京人应该照样能干，转变观念已迫在眉睫 mean in my textbook?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> 据介绍，今年北京的劳动力市场总体上仍供大于求，就业形势依然严峻。**外地人能干的，北京人应该照样能干，转变观念已迫在眉睫**。行文至此，北京市职业介绍部门传来令人欣喜的消息：在招聘的85名保洁员中，有50人是北京人。相信会有越来越多的北京人从外地人离京这一课中受到启发，振奋精神，展示北京人的新风采。
>
> <sub>Short Term Reading Chinese (2nd edition): Advanced; [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1cv8.jpg).</sub>

The above is the last paragraph from a passage in my new textbook about 北京人's prejudice towards 外地人.  During Spring Festival, all the 外地人 go home, and 北京人 don't want to do their jobs, leading to a worker shortage.  北京人 realize their prejudice is wrong.

I don't understand the part in bold, and in particular why 照样 is being used when it was originally the 外地人 doing these jobs.  Baidu Translate gives the following:

> If outsiders are capable, Beijingers should still be capable. It is urgent to change their ideas.

It just seems out of place in context.

**Question**: What does 外地人能干的，北京人应该照样能干，转变观念已迫在眉睫 mean in my textbook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Baidu treated '能干' as the compound word  for "capable"

But 能 and 干 here actually act as a verb and an auxiliary verb 'can' and 'do'

> 外地人(outsiders) 能(can) 干(do) 的(工作)

> 北京人(Pekingese) 应该(should) 照样(also) 能(can) 干(do)

> 转变观念(changing perception) 已(already) 迫在眉睫 (urgently imminent)

"外地人能干的(工作)" -- "(Jobs) that outsiders can do" is the topic

"北京人应该照样能(干)" -- "Pekingese should also can (do)" is the comment

转变观念 is the topic

已迫在眉睫 is the comment

*One of the 北京人's prejudices toward 外地人 is that 外地人 only do lowly jobs, and the more educated, well to do 北京人 can't bother to take those jobs, but this perception is wrong, 北京人 have to realize when you have no job, you have to lower your expectation and be able to take any job available*

Answer (score 2):

外地人能干(able to do/can do)的，北京人应该(should/must/ought to)照样(also)能干，转变(change/altering)观念(concept/perception)已迫在眉睫(is already an urgent necessity)。

照样 - also, follow suit.

In the booming market economy, due to the plenty of job opportunities, and compounded with the deep-rooted traditional social class/status bias, the young native city dwellers often prefer/prioritize the more comfortable white-collar/office jobs, and leave the laborious work to the outsiders (people who mainly came from the rural areas). This article is pledging with the native city dwellers to alter their bias, especially at a time the job opening is scarce.

Answer (score 1):

People outside capital city could perform well on this and so the people coming from the capital city **also** could.  The perception has to be changed.